# WPF Scrollviewer scroll to mouse position

Tags: wpf, image, offset, scrollviewer

I am working on an image viewer control that consists of an image inside of a scrollviewer.
To zoom, I use a scaletransform within the image's layouttransform.
Zoomin is happening on mouse click. If the user clicks on the image, I would like the pixel at the mouse position to be located at the center of the visual area of the scrollviewer.
To achieve this I want to modify the scrollviewer offsets, but I am not sure about how to calculate the correct offset that places the pixel unter the mouse pointer at the center.

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/5202aae5-b2cc-4fc3-aa43-4541fcc856fb) is a description of how to keep the scrollbars at their relative position. That works fine, but is not what I am looking for.

How do you calculate the offsets correctly?

Here is some of my code:

The xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="5" Name="scrvImagePanel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  CanContentScroll="True"
                  DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  Background="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"
                  ScrollChanged="OnScrollChanged">
        <Image Name="imgPicture"
               MouseUp="imgMouseUp" 
               Stretch="None"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               >
            <Image.LayoutTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="imgZoomTransform" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"></ScaleTransform>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.LayoutTransform>                
        </Image>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

and the code:

```
private void imgMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   Point absScreenPos = e.GetPosition(imgPicture);

    //calculate the new zoom factor
    this.ZoomFactor = imgZoomTransform.ScaleX;
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
    {
      this.ZoomFactor /= 2.0;
    }
    else if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
    {
      this.ZoomFactor *= 2.0;
    }

    //perform the zooming
    this.DoZoom(this.ZoomFactor, absScreenPos.X, absScreenPos.Y);

}

private void DoZoom(double zoom, double posX, double posY)
{
  // update the scale transform
  imgZoomTransform.ScaleX = zoom;
  imgZoomTransform.ScaleY = zoom;

  this.AdjustScroll(new Point(posX, posY));
}


private void AdjustScroll(Point? centerPoint)
{
  if(centerPoint != null)
  {
    var sv = this.scrvImagePanel;

    double offsetX = (centerPoint.Value.X / this.imgPicture.ActualWidth) * sv.ActualWidth;
    double offsetY = (centerPoint.Value.Y / this.imgPicture.ActualHeight) * sv.ActualHeight;

    sv.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(offsetX);
    sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(offsetY);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how, but the last answer disappeared. I used your description in AdjustScroll(...) but the scrollbars still sit at offset=0.

Answer (score 4):

The idea is simple, when mouse is down, you should calculate its distance from the center and add or subtract it to or from the current offsets.
Consider this code:

```
bool left = false;
    double scale = 2;
    double ZoomFactor;
    private void imgMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Point absScreenPos = e.GetPosition(imgPicture);

        //calculate the new zoom factor
        this.ZoomFactor = imgZoomTransform.ScaleX;
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
        {
            left = false;
            this.ZoomFactor /= scale;
        }
        else if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        {
            left = true;
            this.ZoomFactor *= scale;
        }
        //perform the zooming
        this.DoZoom(this.ZoomFactor, absScreenPos.X, absScreenPos.Y);
    }
    private void AdjustScroll(Point? centerPoint)
    {
        if (centerPoint != null)
        {
            Point poi = Mouse.GetPosition(scrvImagePanel);

            double Xmove = ( scrvImagePanel.ActualHeight) / 2 - poi.X;
            double Ymove = (scrvImagePanel.ActualWidth) / 2 - poi.Y;

            if (left)
            {
                scrvImagePanel.ScrollToHorizontalOffset((scrvImagePanel.HorizontalOffset - Xmove) * scale);
                scrvImagePanel.ScrollToVerticalOffset((scrvImagePanel.VerticalOffset - Ymove) * scale);
            }
            else
            {
                scrvImagePanel.ScrollToHorizontalOffset((scrvImagePanel.HorizontalOffset - Xmove) / scale);
                scrvImagePanel.ScrollToVerticalOffset((scrvImagePanel.VerticalOffset - Ymove) / scale);
            }
        }
    }
```

**I know that this code does not work perfectly, but I think this must give you the path**

Comment: I tried your code but the scrolling (with zoom disabled) is not correct yet.

Comment: @tabina I'm sorry, it was not what I though first. see the edit. Upped your question maybe others help.